# Origination of Monero terms and phrases

Tags: aeon, monero-terminology, esperanto

I understand that some Monero terms originate from [Esperanto](http://weuse.cash/esperanto-corner/). What is the Monero specific meaning and origination of the following non Esperanto words and phrases?

1. Is it true?
2. Soon
3. Don't buy Monero
4. Darkflarb
5. Going full Pegasus

Please add definitions for any additional well known terms or phrases I overlooked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree with the answer of Jolly Mort with regard to answers 1, 3 and 5. I will add an answer for # 2 and 4 and provide some additional evidence to support the answers Jolly Mort provided.

1. More in the origination of [Is it true?](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=740112.0)

   > One last thing: without doing too much language analysis (which is mostly supposition and bullshit), it's easy to see common grammar and spelling fuck ups. My personal favorite is the "Is it true?" question. You can see it in the Bytecoin thread asking if it's Satoshi's second project, in the Monero thread asking if the Monero devs use a botnet to fake demand, and in the Dashcoin thread confirming the donation address (for a coin whose only claim is that they copy Bytecoin perfectly, what the fuck do they need donations for??).
2. Monero developers are mostly volunteers and have never provided firm deadlines. Since 2014 people frequently asked when an official GUI would arrive. Although a formal explanation is [available](https://forum.getmonero.org/1/news-announcements-and-editorials/190/editorial-why-is-the-official-gui-wallet-not-released-yet), saying "soon" became a common response to questions about specific Monero release dates for the GUI or anything else. Those that want a more precise answer than soon, are encouraged to look at progress in [Github](https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core)
3. Monero speculation has never been encouraged by Monero developers. Instead research, development and buying only for an actual (non speculative) use case has been the standard recommendation to newcomers. Although the "Don't buy Monero phrase" or its equivalent has been used by many Monero community members, this is perhaps the most [high profile example](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/are-any-altcoins-currenty-useful-no-says-monero-developer-riccardo-spagni-1458743546) from core develer Riccardo Spagni.
4. On April 1st 2016 (known as April Fool's day in some countries) the operators of Bitcointalk temporarily replaced the name Monero with Darkflarb. Many people found this funny and still occosionally use the name
5. [Nyancoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1197508.0) in 2014 was the first "Full Pegasus" cryptocurrency moment and led to a nearly complete loss of invested capital. AmericanPegasus did take out a loan to buy some Monero for about 40 cents in 2015, but subsequently sold some Monero to pay off some loans and diversify. Reportedly he now owns large quantities of [Aeon](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1197508.0) and has recently expressed varying levels of interest in [ETC, SIA, IOC and BCY](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1569082.msg15749601#msg15749601). "Going Full Pegasus" may also reference the use of large market orders instead of patiently placing small limit orders over time to open new positions. In the case of Aeon (which far less liquidity than Monero) this led  to a large spike in price when he opened his position. Related to this practice is the phrase "Pegasus pump". American Pegasus is quite transparent and often discloses his position. In the case of Aeon his holding remains visible on the Bittrex exchange distribution chart where he has self identified as the [largest holder](https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName=BTC-AEON).

Answer (score 5):

1. I understand that there was a time when monero community was being "attacked" on the forums by stating various baseless claims in the form of questions "Is it true that ?"
2. No idea. Could refer to long waiting periods for price movement / development milestones.
3. Recent one, I think. It's common for monero seniors and devs to discourage new users from buying monero. Possibly the only crypto where that is so.
4. No idea
5. Americanpegasus, a reddit user and a dedicated monero evangelist, likes to go all-in with investment ideas. I think there was a huge loss involved in one of those where "full pegasus" was coined.